# Get material from object3D after load

Tags: javascript, three.js

I wanna get a material from object after load but i havent access to children of my object

```html
function loadObject () {
    var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    var container = new THREE.Object3D();
    var mesh  = null;
    loader.load( this.link , function ( object ) {
        object.traverse(function (child) {
            if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh){
                var geometry  =  new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(child.geometry);
                mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, child.material);
                mesh.name = 'tibia';
                container.add( mesh );
                console.log(container.children.length);
            }
        });
    });
    return container;
};

var myObject = loadObject();
```

Comment: what does the log log?

Comment: for myObject.children[0] i dont get anything and just for myObject.children i get empty array